# how can i get the columns of a row from database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a form  named **search.php** that searches for a database column **order_niv**

[image]i want to get the values of other columns in the row i searched for if the result is found. i did this `$res = mysqli_query($connz,"SELECT * FROM add_courier WHERE`add_courier`.`id`= 1");`but it only displays a fixed **id** even if i didn't search for the row.

from the image below. if i searched for **AWB567890** i want to get the values of **postal, email, phone** etc in the circled only.

here is my **search.php**

```
<form class="form-inline justify-content-center my-5 subsribe-rounded" action="result.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="order_inv" class="form-control px-4 u-rounded-50 u-h-55" placeholder="shipping number Ej:(AWB-100000001)" required>

                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary u-h-55">
                        Search Tracking
                    </button>
                </form>
```

and the **result.php**

```
$res = mysqli_query($connz,"SELECT * FROM add_courier WHERE `add_courier`.`id` = 1");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

$tracking = $row['tracking'];
$s_name = $row['s_name'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$address = $row['address'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

 }
```

Comment: Why are you specifying `id = 1` if you actually want to find `order_inv = 'AWxxx'`?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the result is not showing cuz you're confusing fetch_array with fetch_assoc.

With fetch_array you use numeric index for the results

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$res1 = $row[0];
```

With fetch_assoc you use column_name as the index for the results

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$res1 = $row['id'];
```

So your code in **result.php** has to be

```
$res = mysqli_query($connz,"SELECT * FROM add_courier WHERE `add_courier`.`id` = 1");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $tracking = $row['tracking'];
    $s_name = $row['s_name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
 }
```

Otherwise, try to print your query result to know if mysql is not returning it, or it has to be with your php usage

```
var_dump($res);
```

or

```
print_r($res);
```